# when iam using the code window.location.href = "#" in .aspx page then scrolling in is not happening properly in internet explorer

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net website i want to disable the back button for one content page. so, i used the below java script code in content page

```
 function changeHashOnLoad() {              
     window.location.href += "#";
     setTimeout("changeHashAgain()", "50");        
 }

 function changeHashAgain() {        
     window.location.href += "1";
 }

 var storedHash = window.location.hash;

 window.setInterval(function () {
     if (window.location.hash != storedHash) {
         window.location.hash = storedHash;
     }
 }, 50);

 changeHashOnLoad();
```

The above code is working correctly in chrome and mozilla firefox, but in internet explorer the page doesnot scrolling properly. Anybody please give the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you do this? Whatever the actual problem is, disabling the back button is not the solution.

Comment: I used this code for disabling back button for particular page. actual problem is, due to the above code scrolling is not happening in internet explorer.

Comment: No. You have some problem for which you have decided that disabling the back button is the solution. This is the wrong solution. However, you're now having issues with implementing this solution, so you're asking a question about your problem with this solution, rather than asking a question about the original problem.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply. My requirement is disabling the back button that is working fine other browsers. now my issue is internet explorer is not scrolling properly. what is the solution for working properly.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML/CSS, preferably in http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Hi lgnask, HTML/CSS have no probelm. but internet explorer is not supported this line window.location.href += "#"; what i need to do instead of this line?